# biber+biblatex+biblatex-chem: when the DOI misteriously decides not to be printed!

Tags: biblatex, doi, biblatex-chem

I've come to face with a small issue. Using Biber+Biblatex, I haven't been able to print out the DOI in the bibliography! I've used `biblatex-chem` and tried both `chem-angew` and `chem-acs`. From what I gathered from the `biblatex-chem` examples, they should automagically print out the DOI. I even thought that perhaps since the .bib file is in BibTeX style it could interfere, so I tried to convert BibTeX to BibLaTeX, to no avail.

Any ideas on the why and how to overcome it?

[image]

```
    \documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright]{book}

% ! Preamble !


\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chem-acs]{biblatex}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\addbibresource{dummy.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{filecontents}{dummy.bib}

    @ARTICLE{A,
        author={G. R. Kilgore},
        journal={Proceedings of the Institute of Radio Engineers},
        title={Magnetostatic Oscillators for Generation of Ultra-Short Waves},
        year={1932},
        volume={20},
        number={11},
        pages={1741-1751},
        doi={10.1109/JRPROC.1932.227710},
        ISSN={0731-5996},
        month={11}
        }

    @Article{B,
        author  = {Winterstein, E.},
        title   = {Zur Erinnerung an Ernst Schulze},
        journal = {Berichte der deutschen chemischen Gesellschaft},
        year    = {1914},
        volume  = {47},
        number  = {1},
        pages   = {429-449},
        doi     = {10.1002/cber.19140470169},
        eprint  = {https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1002/cber.19140470169},
        url     = {https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/cber.19140470169},
        }

    @Article{C,
        author  = {A Gautier},
        title   = {Sur les tyrosamines},
        journal = {Bulletin de la Société chimique de Paris},
        year    = {1906},
        volume  = {35},
        pages   = {1195--1197},
        url     = {https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5499755m},
    }

  @Article{D,
    author       = {G. R. Kilgore},
    title        = {{M}agnetostatic {O}scillators for {G}eneration of {U}ltra-{S}hort {W}aves},
    volume       = {20},
    number       = {11},
    pages        = {1741--1751},
    date         = {1932-11},
    doi          = {10.1109/jrproc.1932.227710},
    journaltitle = {Proceedings of the Institute of Radio Engineers},
    publisher    = {Institute of Electrical and Electronics Engineers ({IEEE})},
  }

\end{filecontents}

This is reference \cite{A} and this is reference \cite{B}. They are different from \cite{C}. Can it be that cleaning up reference \cite{A} into biblatex style makes the difference? We shall see in reference \cite{D}

    \begingroup
     \let\clearpage\relax
     \printbibliography
    \endgroup
\end{document}
```

Comment: A comment in the example bib biblatex-chem.bib says (entry  
@Article{Sofield2004) "An article where the volume and page details
    have deliberately been omitted, to force the use of the
    \textsc{doi}". So it looks as if the style actively suppress the doi, if volume is there.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer It suppresses the DOI if `pages` is there. I think there are several styles that work like this, the idea being that an entry with `pages` was published in a journal with volume, number, pages so that it can be identified unqieuely. But `doi=true` (as in your answer) turns that behaviour off.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions
  {
    doi          = true , 
  }
```

to force the printing of the doi.

[image]

Comment: Outstanding help! Thanks!